# xml markupbuilder in grails changing single quotes in atribute value to &apos;

Tags: grails, groovy, escaping

I am using groovys xml markupbuilder to generate my xml. I have attribute of a tag which has single quote (') as part of its value, and when I set it in the code and do a printout, I see the generated xml has the single quote changed to ' 
Is this automatically converted to single quote when I render this xml string in gsp?
if not how do I retain the single quote in the attribute value?

I tried to escape the single quote using \  but it stil shows &apos in output log
here is the markupbuilder code I have

```
xml.map(id:"worldmap",name:"worldmap"){
                res_row.each{
       area(shape:"circle",alt:it.key,title:it.key,onclick:"loadActivity(\'"+it.key+"\')") 
                }
            }
```

the final attribute should be onclick="loadActivity('New York')"

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can configure the markup-builder to use double quotes:

```
xml.setDoubleQuotes(true)
```

complete example:

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder 

def xml = new MarkupBuilder()
xml.setDoubleQuotes(true)
def res_row = [a:1, b:2]

def text= xml.map(id:"worldmap",name:"worldmap"){
   res_row.each{
     area(shape:"circle",alt:it.key,title:it.key,onclick:"loadActivity('${it.key}')") 
   }
}

println text
```

prints:

```
<map id="worldmap" name="worldmap">
 <area shape="circle" alt="a" title="a" onclick="loadActivity('a')" />
 <area shape="circle" alt="b" title="b" onclick="loadActivity('b')" />
```